# I want to convert string to Date using SqlContext

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").csv("baby_names.csv")
```

[df.show(5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRhlu.png)

[df.printSchema()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pQBv.png)

I want to convert a string to a date and get only the year.

I try -

```
df=df.withColumn("Year",col("Year").cast(DateType()))
```

[But that's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbbmZ.png)

I want to get, for example only 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do like below but if we already have year value then why not directly cast it as int instead of going this way

```
df=df.withColumn("Year",F.year(col("Year").cast(DateType())))
```